# I have a css style but the alignment is fixed in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: css

The below css coding is used in my page. But in chrome it displays the image fine. but in firefox it breaks. I dont know why it shows like that. If anybody know the solution for this please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
.vote
{
    position:absolute;
    margin: 53px 3px 0 115px;
}
```

http://domian.com/mysite/pollpage.php?id=2&mview=72

This is my website page. The vote image alignment is `correct in chrome` but `not in firefox`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...

Now define your main div `#polling .pollpagewidth div .contentbox` `position relative` and give to `img tag position absolute` and define **right** or **bottom value** according to your design

Hi now **add this css** in your **style sheet** and **fixed this problem**

```
#polling .pollpagewidth div .contentbox{
position:relative;
}

.contentbox > img {
    bottom: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 43px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add position relative

```
.contentbox
{
 position: relative;
}
```

and remove margin ,
add bottom and right

```
.vote {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 45px;
}
```